# Assign two variables with ternary operator

Tags: python, variable-assignment, ternary-operator

Is there a way to do variable assignments(as shown below) using ternary operators in python:

```
if(x>1):
    y="yes"
else:
    z="yes"
```

Something like `(x='yes') if(x>1) else (z='yes')`, but this gives an error. Is there any other way to do this?

*I know single variable assignments can be done like this: `x="yes" if(l==0) else "no"`*

**Edit:** Assume x, y & z are assigned with some value before this is run.

Comment: No, you can't do that. Also, note that you can just `print('yes' if condition else 'no')`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know we can print, I wanted to know about assignment statements. Any specific reason why its not supported?

Comment: My point was that you can do it inside the call and the parentheses were redundant. As noted below, because you can't have statements in a ternary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe cool. I hope this functionality is added soon.

Comment: Why? It would lead to much more complex code; after one of these statements, you have to check the same condition again to figure out which name got assigned to to avoid a `NameError`. Where would this be useful?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Example : if x>5 make z=10 else y=10(let z be as it is). Could you do that in a single statement was the question. Anyway I got an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exec` function like this:

```
exec("y='yes'" if x > 1  else "z='yes'")
```

Comment: Nice one. Simple alternative.

Comment: I said this 3 minutes earlier with less code duplication and other less hacky alternatives and I got downvoted instead. Why?

Comment: A little nicer (at least to my eyes): `exec(("y" if x > 1 else "z") + "='yes'")`

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following hack, which employs tuple unpacking:

```
y, z = ('yes', z) if x > 1 else (y, 'yes')
```

Don't miss those parentheses.

I wouldn't really recommend using this as it is harder to understand, has one redundant assignment statements, and uses unpacking unnecessarily. I'd recommend going for the normal `if` statement wherever you can.

This is what it would be with normal `if`s:

```
if x > 1:
    y = 'yes'
    z = z
else:
    y = y
    z = 'yes'
```

Comment: Good one. I was looking for possibilities.

Comment: But this assigns something to both names, whereas the OPs code leaves one unassigned.

Comment: @AlexHall I took this line in the question in account: `(x='yes') if(x>1) else (z='yes')`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: And besides, `y` and `z` would already have to be defined, because there would be no use initializing a variable in a one liner `if` as the value wouldn't exist if the `if` isn't executed.

Comment: @EvilTak Thanks for this. And its a really nice hack.

Comment: @AlexHall yes `y`, `z` & `x` are all defined.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. You can only have expressions, not statements, inside the ternary. `print` works because (in Python 3 at least) it is a function call, therefore an expression; but assignment is always a statement.

Comment: Any specific reason? I mean its supported in other languages why not in python?

Comment: @AniMenon because Python isn't those other languages? What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was expecting something about the language maybe not that "Python isn't those other lang..."

Comment: @AniMenon what do you mean *"something about the language"*? Different languages, obviously and tautologously enough, are different. They make different trade offs in pursuit of different goals.

Comment: @AniMenon:  Why not?  Because Python encourages good practice, so clear code is more important than producing Yet Another Way To Do It.  You can't omit indentation either, but you can in other languages.

Comment: @cdarke I just wanted to know if it was possible & if not why not. Looks like there are hacks. So cool :)

Answer (score 2):

```
varname = 'y' if x > 1 else 'z'
```

If you want to assign a global variable:

```
globals()[varname] = 'yes'
```

If you want to set an attribute on an object:

```
setattr(obj, varname, 'yes')
```

If it's a local variable inside a function, you have to get more hacky:

```
exec('%s = "yes"' % varname)
```

or

```
exec(varname + ' = "yes"')
```

You can of course place the definition of `varname` directly in all of these statements to keep it in one line, I'm just avoiding repetition.

But really it's best to not do any of these. Keep it simple and straightforward.

Comment: @AniMenon I don't know what you mean. I'm setting either `y` or `z` with one value. My `exec` is exactly equivalent to the answer you marked correct, just without mentioning `"yes"` twice.

Comment: I got your method now +1. Nice one, sorry I took time to understand.